# How can I add the marked track to a playlist in cmus?

Tags: cmus

I'd like to quickly add the currently marked track (in view 1, 2 or 4) to my playlist of favorites with a key-bindable command in `cmus`.

The man page doesn't reveal a winning strategy. How to do it?

`:add -p <path>` only seems to accept paths as arguments, and it works on the currently marked playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excerpt from: https://linux.die.net/man/7/cmus-tutorial

> Step 5: The Playlist
>
> The playlist is on view 3. But before we go there, lets add some tracks. Press 2 to go to the simple library view, go to a track you want and press y to add it to the playlist. The only visual feedback you'll get that anything happened is that the hilight will move down one row. Add a few more so you have something to work with.

And this works for my version of `cmus`.

Comment: That was the hint I needed. More detailed steps for conveniently adding tracks to a playlist:


1.) In view 3, mark the playlist with space.
2.) In view 1 or 2, press y on the tracks you want to add.


There is no visual feedback. The tracks are silently added to the previously marked playlist.